# Changing asp hyperlink text to image

Tags: asp.net, css

I have following asp hyperlink:

`<asp:HyperLink ID="a" runat="server" Text="return" NavigateUrl="https://google.com/"></asp:HyperLink`>

What i want is that when user switches to another page instead of this text an image should show up.
Is there any way to change text to image using css? or jquery? or is there any .net function that does that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the imageurl attribute on asp:hyperlink

```
    <asp:HyperLink ID="myHyperlink" runat="server" 
                   ImageUrl="imageLocation.png" Text="return"        
                   NavigateUrl="https://google.com/">
    </asp:HyperLink>
```

Edit: You could give the hyperlink a specific id and target it's first child which would be the image and use .toggle() to remove it and then add the text you want with .html().

In Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#<%= myHyperlink.ClientID%>").children( ":first" ).toggle();
    $("#<%= myHyperlink.ClientID%>").html("This is text");
});
```

Think that should work. Sorry for not reading properly before.

Comment: but how will i change the image again with css in next page??

Answer (score 0):

css (image is assuming you want it 16X16px)

```
.showtext{color:#000;}
.showimage{background-image:url(/my/image.jpg); width:16px; height:16px;}
```

check for the hyperlink control in your codebehind and populate it based on the page. Maybe something like.

```
if(Request.ServerVariables["SCRIPT_NAME"]=="/mypage.aspx")
{
    hyperlink1.Text="Return";
    hyperlink1.CssClass="showtext";
}
else
{
    hyperlink1.Text=" ";
    hyperlink1.CssClass="showimage";
}
```